# XCode Continuos Integration - Device Not Suported

Tags: xcode, osx-server

I've been trying to setup Xcode Server for Continuous integration, but when connect the device appears "not supported" . Any help why this happen [image]?

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears to be a problem when setup Xcode Server, on OSXServer. I just turn off XCode and turn on again and the device was recognized correctly.